# select TOP designated employees per department in a single query

Tags: sql-server

How to find the top designated employees per department?

I have this table and values:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#deptartment]
(
  [emp_id] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [dept_name] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
  [emp_name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL ,
  [desig] [VARCHAR](100) NULL
)
ON  [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('IT','JAFFERY','DIRECTOR')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DEVELOPMENT','CORBIT','PROGRAMMER')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DEVELOPMENT','CHANDRA','DBA')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('IT','KEVIN','MANAGER')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('IT','ROBERT','SUPERVISOR')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('QA','NOMAN','ANALYST')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('ADMIN','CORE','RECEPTIONIST')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('QA','MADDEN','ANALYST')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('IT','NORRIS','TECHNICIAN')
INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('ADMIN','PATRICK','CLERK')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DATA','SONJA','SUPERVISOR')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('QA','GEORGE','MANAGER')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('ADMIN','EMILLY','MANAGER')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('QA','PATRICK','TESTER')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DEVELOPMENT','ABDUL','MANAGER')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DATA','PATRICK','CLERK')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('ADMIN','GEORGE','CLERK')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DEVELOPMENT','YURIY','SUPERVISOR')
 INSERT INTO #deptartment  VALUES ('DATA','GRAHAM','OPERATOR')
```

Here is the query that I've tried:

```
   SELECT  D1.dept_name, D1.desig,
    RANK() OVER(Partition  BY D1.DESIG ORDER BY  D1.dept_name,D1.DESIG 
   DESC) 
   AS RANKNUMBER 
   FROM  #deptartment D1 GROUP BY D1.desig, D1.dept_name
   ORDER BY RANKNUMBER  DESC
```

Comment: please remove the CAPS in your post, that's not the way to get attention

Comment: next , please show us the effort you have made in answering this question for yourself. we're not here to write your code for you, but we will help you solve problems you are having in your attempts to solve it yourself.

Comment: You need clear designation which role is higher than other per department. For example `DBA` and `PROGRAMMER` are they equal?

Comment: which designation is a top designation

Comment: Give us estimated output

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a conditional ranking / order. Pay attention to the `order by case` statement. You need to finish this statement to place the order of `desig` according to what ever your definition of *top designated employee* is. I made some assumptions for the first three, but just be sure to list them all for each unique value of `desig`

```
select
    x.emp_id
    ,x.dept_name
    ,x.emp_name
from(
    select
        d.emp_id
        ,d.dept_name
        ,d.emp_name
        ,row_number() over (partition by d.dept_name order by case 
                                                                when d.desig = 'DIRECTOR' then 1
                                                                when d.desig = 'SUPERVISOR' then 2
                                                                when d.desig = 'OPERATOR' then 3
                                                                --etc...
                                                                end) as RN
    from #deptartment d) x
where x.RN = 1
```